# Using ImportRange in a template and maintaining sheet association

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I have a sheet (SheetA) that is a template in the GSuite template library.

SheetA uses the importrange function to import data from another sheet (SheetB). SheetA has been associated to the other sheet.

When a new sheet (SheetC) is created using the template (File->New From Template) the import has to be manually authorised between SheetC and SheetB, even though the template SheetA already had the authorisation in place.

Is there anyway that the re-authorization can be avoided as it was authorized in the original SheetA already?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authorization **has never been done** between `SheetB` and `SheetC` so if you want to use the `IMPORTRANGE`, you need to allow the access to it.

When you are importing data from the `SheetB` you are only authorizing `SheetA` to access it - not all the other sheets.

So if you want to import data from `SheetB` into the `SheetC`, you need to authorize this again as this time it's **another sheet** requesting the data.

According to the `IMPORTRANGE` documentation:

> Spreadsheets must be explicitly granted permission to pull data from other spreadsheets using `IMPORTRANGE`. The first time the **destination sheet** pulls data from a new source sheet, the user will be prompted to grant permission. Once access is granted, any editor on the **destination spreadsheet** can use `IMPORTRANGE` to pull from any part of the source spreadsheet.

#### Reference

- [IMPORTRANGE Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks, not the answer I was hoping for!